# How to get Magento 2 Country Collection

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I hope you are doing well.

I want to get all the countries in the below format.

```
$countries = [
  "AU" => "Australia",
  "IN" => "India",
  "US" => "United States",
  "UK" => "United Kingdom",
  .......
]
```

I tried but no use, i am always getting CountryId as 2 digit names like

```
$countries = [
  0 => "AU",
  1 => "IN",
  2 => "US",
  3 => "UK",
  .......
]
```

I have used the following code

```
Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection::loadByStore()
```

How can i achieve this in Magento 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use my simple code: (can ez injection class)

```
    public function getCountries()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory */
        $countryCollectionFactory = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory::class);

        /** @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $countryCollection */
        $countryCollection = $countryCollectionFactory->create();

        $countryCollection = $countryCollection->toOptionArray();

        return array_column($countryCollection, 'label', 'value');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop through the country collection and create a new array with the country code as key and the country name as value. Could you try something like this?

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
    $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getCountryName($countryCode){
    $country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
    return $country->getName();
}

public function getCountryCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore();
    return $collection;
}

public function getCountries()
{
    $countryCollection = $this->getCountryCollection();

    $countries = [];
    foreach ($countryCollection->getData() as $country) {
        $countries[$country['country_id']] = $this->getCountryName($country['country_id']);
    }

    return $countries;
}
```

Then in your template you can get the countries with $block->getCountries().

Result:

```
array(249) { ["AD"]=> string(7) "Andorra" ["AE"]=> string(28) "Verenigde Arabische Emiraten" ["AF"]=> string(11) "Afghanistan" ["AG"]=> string(18) "Antigua en Barbuda" ["AI"]=> string(8) "Anguilla" ["AL"]=> string(8) "Albanië" ["AM"]=> string(8) "Armenië" ["AN"]=> NULL ["AO"]=> string(6) "Angola" ["AQ"]=> string(10) "Antarctica" ["AR"]=> string(11) "Argentinië" ["AS"]=> string(16) "Amerikaans-Samoa" ["AT"]=> string(10) "Oostenrijk" ["AU"]=> string(10) "Australië" ["AW"]=> string(5) "Aruba" ["AX"]=> string(6) "Åland" ...
```